# Wildcard certificate not valid for mydomain.com

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, subdomain, wildcard

I created Wildcard certificate to support my site domain and subdomains.
The new certificate works for my subdomains (e.g www.mydomain.com , sub.mydomain.com)
But when I try to get to mydomain.com I get certificate warning: "the certificate is only valid for *.mydomain.com"

Is it a problem with my configuration or just the Wildcard certificate doesn't support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For supporting both `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com` the certificate needs to include both `*.example.com` and `example.com` as subject alternative names. I assume that the last one is missing from your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have purchased wildcard ssl certificate from thawte or symantec, which does not support equally www and non-www.  In the past, I purchased thawte wildcard certificate and faced the same type of issue. I just discussed with my vendor to get the solution, they gave me technical support instantly and suggest alphassl wildcard - 
https://www.ssl2buy.com/alphassl-wildcard.php. After that, I switched over to alphassl wildcard that works fine on my both domain names mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com as well anything.mydomain.com.